How to add a nonce check correctly to this specific code?
Here's what I have so far:
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_process', 'test_process' );

function test_process( $data ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    test_errorsonoff();
    test_process_watch( $data );
    test_errorsonoff( 'off' );
}

function test_process_watch( $data ) {
    if ( !array_key_exists( 'func', $_GET ) ) {
        _e( ' Not Found', 'test-plugin' );
        exit();
    }
    $trash     = TEST_PLUGIN_URL . 'images/trash.png';
    $tdown     = TEST_PLUGIN_URL . 'images/tdown.png';
    $tup       = TEST_PLUGIN_URL . 'images/tup.png';
    $whois     = TEST_PLUGIN_URL . 'images/whois.png';
    $ip        = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['ip'] );
    $email     = sanitize_email( $_GET['email'] );
    $container = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['cont'] );
    $func      = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['func'] );
    $options = test_get_options();
    $stats   = test_get_stats();
    $ansa    = array();
    switch ( $func ) {
        case 'delete_gcache':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_remove_gcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            $show = be_load( 'test_get_gcache', 'x', $stats, $options );
            echo $show;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'delete_bcache':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_remove_bcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            $show = be_load( 'test_get_bcache', 'x', $stats, $options );
            echo $show;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'add_black':
            if ( $container == 'badips' ) {
                be_load( 'test_remove_bcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            } else if ( $container == 'goodips' ) {
                be_load( 'test_remove_gcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            } else {
                be_load( 'test_remove_bcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
                be_load( 'test_remove_gcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            }
            be_load( 'test_addtoblocklist', $ip, $stats, $options );
            break;
        case 'add_white':
            if ( $container == 'badips' ) {
                be_load( 'test_remove_bcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            } else if ( $container == 'goodips' ) {
                be_load( 'test_remove_gcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            } else {
                be_load( 'test_remove_bcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
                be_load( 'test_remove_gcache', $ip, $stats, $options );
            }
            be_load( 'test_addtoallowlist', $ip, $stats, $options );
            break;
        case 'delete_wl_row':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_get_alreq', $ip, $stats, $options );
            echo $ansa;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'delete_wlip':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_get_alreq', $ip, $stats, $options );
            echo $ansa;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'delete_wlem':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_get_alreq', $ip, $stats, $options );
            echo $ansa;
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            _e( '\r\n\r\nUnrecognized function "' . $func . '"', 'test-plugin' );
            exit();
    }
    $ajaxurl  = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    $cachedel = 'delete_gcache';
    switch ( $container ) {
        case 'badips':
            $show = be_load( 'test_get_bcache', 'x', $stats, $options );
            echo $show;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'goodips':
            $show = be_load( 'test_get_gcache', 'x', $stats, $options );
            echo $show;
            exit();
            break;
        case 'wlreq':
            $ansa = be_load( 'test_get_alreq', $ip, $stats, $options );
            echo $ansa;
            exit();
        default:
            _e( 'Error ' . $container . ' ', 'test-plugin' );
            exit();
    }
}


How is that code called? How is the nonce passed in?

@Rup I added the second part.

Thanks, but that's the part your original code calls. I meant what calls your original code, i.e. what calls test_process(). Is it a form post handled on page load, an admin-ajax handler, a REST handler? Are you passing a nonce in and just need to validate it, or do you need to add that too?

@Rup The function is only called once within the same file: add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_process', 'test_process' );.

The first thing is to inline the nonce so that you can use it in the script that calls the ajax action.
// plugin or theme php file
wp_enqueue_script(
    'your-script-handle',
    'url/to/your/script.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    null,
    true
);

wp_add_inline_script(
    'your-script-handle',
    'const YourAjaxConfig = ' . json_encode( array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'action' => 'test_process',
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'test_process_nonce' ),
        ),
    ) ),
    'before'
);

Get the nonce value from the config object and pass it along the ajax call.
// script.js
jQuery.post(
    YourAjaxConfig.ajax.url,
    {
        action: YourAjaxConfig.ajax.action,
        _ajax_nonce: YourAjaxConfig.ajax.nonce,
    },
    function($data) {
        // do something with the response
    }
);

Then use for example check_ajax_referer() to check that the request has a valid nonce in it.
// ajax handler php file
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_process', 'test_process' );
function test_process() {
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'test_process_nonce', false, false ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nonce', 400 );
    }

    // code...

    wp_send_json_success( 'test_process done' );
}

P.S. using WP AJAX is a bit old school nowadays. You could consider using WP REST instead. See the handbook for REST nonce example.
